# How to make documents added to an embedded Solr Server with SolrJ visible to a http Solr query

Tags: grails, solr, solrj

We have a GRAILS / SOLR application that uses a SOLRJ EmbeddedSolrServer to add / retrieve data.  The application is also set up to be accessible by http.

When I index documents by http I can reload the SOLR core and the changes are now visible to the Embedded Server.

However when I add documents by using the EmbeddedSolrServer the records are not visible using http unless I restart SOLR itself.

The records are visible to queries using the Embedded Server at this point.

I've tried running reload core commands via curl and the SOLR admin interface but the docs remain hidden until I restart.

Has anyone any idea how I can make these records visible via http without restarting SOLR?

Thanks for your help.

SOLR is 2.1.0
Grails is 2.4.2
We're running on OS X 10.10.5

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference between getting results via http or directly from the embedded server.
When you restart solr, you trigger a hard commit so the cache is flushed and the reader picks up the updated index. So I believe you have 2 options:

1. Change the solrconfig.xml to trigger a hard commit after a given period of time or after a given number of documents;
2. Trigger the hard commit using SolrJ.

You can find more info about differences between hard and soft commit [here](https://lucidworks.com/blog/2013/08/23/understanding-transaction-logs-softcommit-and-commit-in-sorlcloud//).
Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38762062/solrj-expicit-commit-required-after-add/38763037?noredirect=1#comment65100223_38763037) answer for a concrete example including SolrJ and config.

Comment: Thanks for the response @AR1.  I've read the page you linked and while I still can't get this to work using SolrJ I have managed to hack something together with a curl being executed at the end of the inserts (I've just noticed my original question said that curl didn't work that's weird!)